# Maximum number of simplexes given n-element point sets in the plane

Tags: geometry, simplicial-stuff, combinatorial-geometry

Does anyone know if it has been proved what the maximum number of simplexes occurring in the plane is for a given value of $n$ points? I am interested in this question in relation to packing problems (eventually generalizing to tetrahedron packing in 3-space).

In 1974, Harborth proved the following theorem by applying Euler's polyhedral formula and using induction.

> Let $f_{2}^{\text{min}}(n)$ denote the maximum number of times the minimum distance can occur among n points in the plane. Then, $$f_{2}^{\text{min}}(n) = \lfloor 3n - \sqrt{12n -3} \rfloor$$

For any dimension $d$, we have a general definition for the maximum number of times the minimum distance can occur among $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^d$ as, $$f_{d}^{\text{min}}(n) = \max_{|P|=n} | \{\overline{pq} | p,q \in P \text{ and } |p-q|=1\}|$$
where $P \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ is any $n$-element point set. We now wish to extend this result to not only consider the maximum number of times the minimum distance can occur among $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^d$, but to the maximum number of times a regular $k$-simplex of minimum side length can occur among $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Toward the end, I define the $\Delta$-function as follows:

> Let $\widehat{v_{1}...v_{k}}$ denote a $k$-simplex with vertices $v_{1},...,v_{k} \in \mathbb{R}^d$. Then,
>   $$\Delta_{d}^{k}(n) = \max_{|P|=n} | \{\widehat{v_{1}...v_{k}} | v_{1},...,v_{k} \in P, |v_{i}-v_{j}|=1, i\neq j\}|$$
>   defines the maximum number of occurrences of a regular $k$-simplex of minimum edge length determined by an $n$-element point set in $P \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$.

So, in terms of this $\Delta$-function, we have $f_{2}^{\text{min}}(n) = \Delta_{2}^{1}(n) = \lfloor 3n - \sqrt{12n -3} \rfloor$. I am now interested in extending Harborth's result to $\Delta_{2}^{2}(n)$ and in doing so I have proved the following corollary of two lemmas I proved (I will not mention the proofs).

> Any simplicial $k$-complex $\mathcal{K}$ for which $\Delta_{d}^{k}(n)=|\mathcal{K}|$ is connected and homogeneous, where $k \leq d$ for $P \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ with $|P|=n$.

I now want to extend Harborth's result to determining $\Delta_{2}^{2}(n)$, that is, determining the maximum number of regular triangles of side length equal to the minimum distance that can occur among an $n$-element point set in the plane.

The start of my proof looks something like this, I am stuck though and am looking for guidance.

> By Corollary 1, we have that $\Delta_{2}^{2}(n)=|\mathcal{K}|$ where $\mathcal{K}$ is a connected homogeneous simplicial $2$-complex. By the necessity of homogeneity, $\partial \mathcal{K}$ is a closed polygon (is it necessarily convex?) with at most $n$-vertices. Let the degree of a vertex in $\mathcal{K}$ denote the number of adjacent vertices in $\mathcal{K}$. Then, let $b$ and $b_{d}$ denote the total number of vertices of $\partial \mathcal{K}$, and the number of those vertices that have degree $d$ in $\mathcal{K}$, respectively. Then, $b = b_{2} + b_{3} + b_{4} + b_{5}$. [From here, I don't know where to go, I want to employ Euler's polyhedron formula somehow. If $\partial \mathcal{K}$ is convex, could I say $\Delta_{2}^{2} = 2 - n + E(n)$, where $E(n)$ is a function which determines the number of edges of $\mathcal{K}$? Any ideas for how to determine E(n)?]

I appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: In the plane any three noncolinear points determine a triangle (equiv. a 2-simplex), so presumably you are asking about the maximum number of simplices with disjoint interior.  I believe this is an easy application of Euler's formula.

Comment: @hardmath, I think Samuel wants all the triangles to be congruent and equilateral (although I must say this isn't entirely clear).

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Yes, I intended the triangles to all be congruent and equilateral, I apologize for the confusion. Is this just an easy application of Euler's polyhedral formula still?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thanks, I'm still wondering if the equilateral triangles are allowed to overlap.  The mention of packings suggests this would not be allowed.  Of course it is known that a lattice packing of equilateral triangles is optimal in the plane, but perhaps there's something more subtle to the Question.

Comment: @hardmath: The simplexes are not allowed to overlap, think of it like this. What is the maximum number of simplexes possible given a connected homogeneous simplicial complex formed from n-vertices?

Comment: Title says plane, body says dimension $d$. Which is it? 4 points in the plane gives at most 2 (unit equilateral triangles), 4 points in 3-space can give 4, so it makes a difference. I think you need to think through your problem and decide what you really mean to ask and then edit accordingly.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I was trying to avoid adding too much detail, but I've fully explained my question and exactly where I am stuck. Hopefully you have some ideas for where I might be able to go from here. Thank you.

Comment: Dumitrescu, Pach, and Toth, The maximum number of empty congruent triangles determined by a point set, might be of interest, at  http://www.math.nyu.edu/~pach/publications/triangles050605.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is given the vertices and equilateral triangles are connected "edge to edge" in the plane, [Euler's formula for "faces" of planar graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Planar_graphs) applies whether or not the simplicial complex is convex.  Note that the count of faces includes one unbounded region in the plane, so:

$$n - 1 = e - s$$

where $n$ is the number of vertices, $e$ the number of (unit) edges, and $s$ the number of (unit) equilateral triangles (simplices).  Let $f(n)$ denote the maximum possible $s$ for given $n$.

The vertices may be counted by degree, as you started to do:

$$n = b_2 + b_3 + b_4 + b_5 + b_6$$

where $b_i$ counts the vertices of degree $i$.  Then, since every edge is between two vertices, $e = (2b_2 + 3b_3 + 4b_4 + 5b_5 + 6b_6)/2$.

Consider the special case that $n$ is a [centered hexagonal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centered_hexagonal_number), say $3m^2 + 3m + 1$, with the vertices are arranged accordingly.  Then number of simplices (unit equilateral triangles) packed in that way is $6m^2$.  The vertices include $b_3 = 6$, $b_4 = 6(m-1)$, and $b_6 = 3m^2 - 3m + 1$, and the number of edges may computed accordingly as $9m^2 + 3m$.

These arrangements show that the ratio $f(n)/n$ tends in the limit to $2$.  Note that $f(n)$ is strictly increasing for $n \ge 2$, because where an exterior edge exists, adding a vertex can add at least one simplex.  I conjecture that $f(n+1) - f(n)$ is always one or two, and that optimal arrangements can be built from the centered hexagonal "building blocks".

Comment: It seems curious, but there's a paper published just last year about [Isoperimetrically Optimal Polygons in the Triangular Grid](http://www.springerlink.com/content/g57245q76832j617/).  In particularly authors Nagy and Barczi prove that the hexagon has the least perimeter for a given area as well as the maximum area for a given perimeter.  I was going to sketch a proof of this, but it seems this is a fairly active research topic.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I ended coming up with an answer of $\Delta_{2}^{2}(n) = 1 - n + \Delta_{2}^{1}(n)$ in terms of my terminology. I appreciate the answer and the reference to the paper by Nagy and Barczi.